# How to update the App-Icon for NativeScript Android

Tags: android, nativescript

I have an app that has already been deployed to PlayStore. With the new update I want this app to display a slightly different icon and startscreen than it currently does.

My `styles.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!-- theme to use FOR launch screen-->
    <style name="LaunchScreenThemeBase" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="toolbarStyle">@style/NativeScriptToolbarStyle</item>

        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/ns_primary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/ns_primaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/ns_accent</item>

        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_screen</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>

        <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>

        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="LaunchScreenTheme" parent="LaunchScreenThemeBase">
    </style>

    <!-- theme to use AFTER launch screen is loaded-->
    <style name="AppThemeBase" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="toolbarStyle">@style/NativeScriptToolbarStyle</item>

        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/ns_primary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/ns_primaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/ns_accent</item>

        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppThemeBase">
    </style>

    <!-- theme for actioon-bar -->
    <style name="NativeScriptToolbarStyleBase" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar">
        <item name="android:background">@color/ns_primary</item>
        <item name="theme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar</item>
        <item name="popupTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat</item>

    </style>

    <style name="NativeScriptToolbarStyle" parent="NativeScriptToolbarStyleBase">
    </style>
</resources>
```

My `colors.xml`:

```
<resources>
    <color name="ns_primary">#F5F5F5</color>
    <color name="ns_primaryDark">#757575</color>
    <color name="ns_accent">#33B5E5</color>
    <color name="ns_blue">#272734</color>
</resources>
```

From my `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<application
        android:name="com.tns.NativeScriptApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
>
```

And I have a lot of drawable-folders where some `.png's` are in (`icon.png` and `splashscreen.9.png`). Now if I simply try to remove these and put the new .png-files into, I get an exception when trying `tns run android`.

I already tried removing the platforms and readding it (With cleaning the npm cache) and just deleting the `.gradle`-directory. I also searched in my root-directory for `.png`, `icon` and `splashscreen` and no other pictures where found (all up-to-date).

I am not sure what else I should try and asking google did not help me so far.

The error:

```
15:25:01.117 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.Project] AAPT(QueuedJob{
title=Cruncher notify_panel_notification_icon_bg.png,
task={from=C:\Dev\biff\HandyApp\platforms\android\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\26.0.0-alpha1\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\notify_panel_notification_icon_bg.png, to=C:\Dev\biff\HandyApp\platforms\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\F0F1F2F3\debug\drawable-xhdpi-v4\notify_panel_notification_icon_bg.png},
future=com.google.common.util.concurrent.SettableFuture@9c66ab1}) discarded: Crunching C:\Dev\biff\HandyApp\platforms\android\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\26.0.0-alpha1\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\notify_panel_notification_icon_bg.png
15:25:01.118 [QUIET] [system.out] Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
15:25:01.118 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.Project] AAPT out(Facade for 1223856843): Crunching single PNG file: C:\Dev\biff\HandyApp\platforms\android\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\26.0.0-alpha1\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\notify_panel_notification_icon_bg.png
15:25:01.118 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.Project] AAPT out(Facade for 1223856843): -> QueuedJob{
title=Cruncher notify_panel_notification_icon_bg.png,
task={from=C:\Dev\biff\HandyApp\platforms\android\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\26.0.0-alpha1\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\notify_panel_notification_icon_bg.png, to=C:\Dev\biff\HandyApp\platforms\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\F0F1F2F3\debug\drawable-xhdpi-v4\notify_panel_notification_icon_bg.png},
future=com.google.common.util.concurrent.SettableFuture@9c66ab1}
15:25:01.118 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.Project] AAPT notify(QueuedJob{
title=Cruncher notify_panel_notification_icon_bg.png,
task={from=C:\Dev\biff\HandyApp\platforms\android\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\26.0.0-alpha1\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\notify_panel_notification_icon_bg.png, to=C:\Dev\biff\HandyApp\platforms\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\F0F1F2F3\debug\drawable-xhdpi-v4\notify_panel_notification_icon_bg.png},
future=com.google.common.util.concurrent.SettableFuture@9c66ab1}): Crunching single PNG file: C:\Dev\biff\HandyApp\platforms\android\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\26.0.0-alpha1\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\notify_panel_notification_icon_bg.png
15:25:01.118 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter] Removed task artifact state for {} from context.
15:25:01.118 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.Project] AAPT(QueuedJob{
title=Cruncher notify_panel_notification_icon_bg.png,
task={from=C:\Dev\biff\HandyApp\platforms\android\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\26.0.0-alpha1\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\notify_panel_notification_icon_bg.png, to=C:\Dev\biff\HandyApp\platforms\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\F0F1F2F3\debug\drawable-xhdpi-v4\notify_panel_notification_icon_bg.png},
future=com.google.common.util.concurrent.SettableFuture@9c66ab1}) discarded: Crunching single PNG file: C:\Dev\biff\HandyApp\platforms\android\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\26.0.0-alpha1\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\notify_panel_notification_icon_bg.png
15:25:01.118 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.Project] AAPT out(Facade for 1223856843):  Output file: C:\Dev\biff\HandyApp\platforms\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\F0F1F2F3\debug\drawable-xhdpi-v4\notify_panel_notification_icon_bg.png
15:25:01.118 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.Project] AAPT out(Facade for 1223856843): -> QueuedJob{
title=Cruncher notify_panel_notification_icon_bg.png,
task={from=C:\Dev\biff\HandyApp\platforms\android\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\26.0.0-alpha1\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\notify_panel_notification_icon_bg.png, to=C:\Dev\biff\HandyApp\platforms\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\F0F1F2F3\debug\drawable-xhdpi-v4\notify_panel_notification_icon_bg.png},
future=com.google.common.util.concurrent.SettableFuture@9c66ab1}
15:25:01.118 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.Project] AAPT notify(QueuedJob{
title=Cruncher notify_panel_notification_icon_bg.png,
task={from=C:\Dev\biff\HandyApp\platforms\android\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\26.0.0-alpha1\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\notify_panel_notification_icon_bg.png, to=C:\Dev\biff\HandyApp\platforms\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\F0F1F2F3\debug\drawable-xhdpi-v4\notify_panel_notification_icon_bg.png},
future=com.google.common.util.concurrent.SettableFuture@9c66ab1}):        Output file: C:\Dev\biff\HandyApp\platforms\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\F0F1F2F3\debug\drawable-xhdpi-v4\notify_panel_notification_icon_bg.png
15:25:01.118 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter] Finished executing task ':mergeF0F1F2F3DebugResources'
15:25:01.119 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.Project] AAPT(QueuedJob{
title=Cruncher notify_panel_notification_icon_bg.png,
task={from=C:\Dev\biff\HandyApp\platforms\android\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\26.0.0-alpha1\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\notify_panel_notification_icon_bg.png, to=C:\Dev\biff\HandyApp\platforms\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\F0F1F2F3\debug\drawable-xhdpi-v4\notify_panel_notification_icon_bg.png},
future=com.google.common.util.concurrent.SettableFuture@9c66ab1}) discarded:     Output file: C:\Dev\biff\HandyApp\platforms\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\F0F1F2F3\debug\drawable-xhdpi-v4\notify_panel_notification_icon_bg.png
15:25:01.119 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.Project] AAPT out(Facade for 1223856843): Done
15:25:01.119 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.Project] AAPT out(Facade for 1223856843): -> QueuedJob{
title=Cruncher notify_panel_notification_icon_bg.png,
task={from=C:\Dev\biff\HandyApp\platforms\android\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\26.0.0-alpha1\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\notify_panel_notification_icon_bg.png, to=C:\Dev\biff\HandyApp\platforms\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\F0F1F2F3\debug\drawable-xhdpi-v4\notify_panel_notification_icon_bg.png},
future=com.google.common.util.concurrent.SettableFuture@9c66ab1}
15:25:01.119 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.Project] AAPT notify(QueuedJob{
title=Cruncher notify_panel_notification_icon_bg.png,
task={from=C:\Dev\biff\HandyApp\platforms\android\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\26.0.0-alpha1\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\notify_panel_notification_icon_bg.png, to=C:\Dev\biff\HandyApp\platforms\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\F0F1F2F3\debug\drawable-xhdpi-v4\notify_panel_notification_icon_bg.png},
future=com.google.common.util.concurrent.SettableFuture@9c66ab1}): Done
15:25:01.119 [LIFECYCLE] [class org.gradle.internal.buildevents.TaskExecutionLogger] :mergeF0F1F2F3DebugResources FAILED
15:25:01.119 [INFO] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor] :mergeF0F1F2F3DebugResources (Thread[Daemon worker Thread 2,5,main]) completed. Took 7.194 secs.
15:25:01.119 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationWorkerRegistry] Worker root.45 completed (0 in use)
15:25:01.119 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor] Task worker [Thread[Daemon worker Thread 2,5,main]] finished, busy: 26.976 secs, idle: 0.069 secs
15:25:01.123 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
15:25:01.123 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
15:25:01.123 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
15:25:01.123 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
15:25:01.124 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Execution failed for task ':mergeF0F1F2F3DebugResources'.
15:25:01.126 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] > Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
15:25:01.126 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
15:25:01.126 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Exception is:
15:25:01.127 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':mergeF0F1F2F3DebugResources'.
```

Comment: As I understand with your question that you need to update the app icon right?

Comment: app icon and splashscreen, yeah

Comment: Then what is the problem replacing the drawable name icon with your new icon? If Android Studio is creating the problem then just invalidate it and restart

Comment: Since I am using NativeScript I am not developing with AndroidStudio. I updated my post

Answer (score 7, accepted):

NativeScript 4.x.x. and above has introduced a CLI commands for automatic generation and replacement of the app icons and the splash screen.

To change the app icons for both Android and iOS

```
tns resources generate icons  ../myIcon.png
```

To change the splash screen for both Android and iOS

```
tns resources generate splashes ../myImage.png --background "#FF00FF"
```

More about these features in the official documetantion [here](https://docs.nativescript.org/tooling/docs-cli/project/configuration/resources/resources-generate-icons) and [here](https://docs.nativescript.org/tooling/docs-cli/project/configuration/resources/resources-generate-splashes).

Comment: I have a problem with this solution, I use my logo image of size 1024x1024 (as recommended), but however, when I generate by using 'tns resources generate icon icon.png', the icon does not appear in full size on the home screen (I use Google Pixel XL). The same happens when I use this service http://nsimage.brosteins.com/

Comment: I had an issue with this solution on nativescript 8.1.1, nativescript/android 8.1.1 with svelte 3.44.0. After generating resources using the commands shown above. Only the splashes were generated successfully. However the icons didn't work as described, hence I had to generate my app launcher icons on https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-launcher.html. Then copied the contents of the 'res' directory to `App_Resources/Android/src/main/res` replacing all the directories with the same names (i.e. `mipmap-anydpi-v26, mipmap-hdpi` etc).